# How to convert .dst file to .jpg format using python?

Tags: python

I have a lot of `.dst` files. I have to convert all files into `.jpg`.  I tried with `pyembroidery` module in python, but I don't know how to save the conversion file. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Show your code - [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Using below method you can convert .dst into png format files. You can also read .dst/.jpg/.pes files by using their commands. Recently, I developed simple application that can convert multiple embroidery files into images and save in particular folder.

```py
import pyembroidery

filepath=r'C://Users//Desktop//file.DST'

pattern=pyembroidery.read_dst(filepath)

var=pyembroidery.write_png(pattern, 'C://Users//Desktop//filename.jpg')

print(pattern)

print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Import the `Image` module from PIL the `os` module.
2. Import the image to be converted using the `Image.open()` method.
3. Display the size of the image before the conversion using the `os.path.getsize()` method.
4. Convert the image using the `Image.convert()` method. Pass "RGB" as the parameter.
5. Export the image using the `Image.save()` method.
6. Display the size of the image after the conversion using the `os.path.getsize()` method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).